# tensorflow error with cuda

Tags: python, tensorflow

when I using tensorflow ,I meet with a error:

```
    [W 09:27:49.213 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/4e889506-2258-481c-b18e-d6a8e920b606/channels?session_id=0665F3F07C004BBAA7CDF6601B6E2BA1 (127.0.0.1): Kernel does not exist: 4e889506-2258-481c-b18e-d6a8e920b606
    [W 09:27:49.266 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/4e889506-2258-481c-b18e-d6a8e920b606/channels?session_id=0665F3F07C004BBAA7CDF6601B6E2BA1 (127.0.0.1) 340.85ms referer=None
    [W 09:27:50.337 NotebookApp] /home/dxq/g++ doesn't exist
    [W 09:27:50.514 NotebookApp] /home/dxq/gcc doesn't exist
    [I 09:28:03.159 NotebookApp] Kernel started: aa5e56b4-df58-4e74-8dc1-96a4cee847aa
    [I 09:28:04.032 NotebookApp] Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel aa5e56b4-df58-4e74-8dc1-96a4cee847aa
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:132] Internal: failed initializing StreamExecutor for CUDA device ordinal 0: Internal: failed call to cuCtxCreate: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY; total memory reported: 18446744071514750976
```

what's wrong with here?

Here is the full spec:

```
ubuntu 16.04
cuda:8.0
python 2.7
```

Comment: I guess you are running two different tensorflow gpu programs?

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command in terminal:

```
nvidia-smi
```

You will get an output like this.
[image]

You will get a summary of the processes occupying the memory of your GPU. In notebooks, even if no cell is running currently, but previously being run and the local server is still on, the memory will be occupied. You will have to stop whichever process is occupying more memory to allocate some bandwidth for your current process to run.

Answer (score 0):

Check the cuDNN version. It should be 5.1